# Re-adding a UPS Sychronization Connection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I have a SharePoint 2010 User Profile Service Sychronization service that has acted up in the past and now I find that it's flat out refused to start. I did some investigating and found that somehow the User Profile Service service application has lost its Synchonization connections; there are none showing up in the Synchronization connection list. I plan to do the following:

1. Delete and recreate the User Profile Service service application using the current UPS databases.
2. Create a new synchronization connection.

I don't want users to lose their Mysite data. My question is, if I recreate a new connection, will this affect the current users' data?

Comment: is ur User profile Sync services is runing? check from services on server.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE That's the one I've been having problems with. I try to start it and it just sits in "Starting" status, but never starts. This is one of the reasons I want to recreate the UPS service application.

Comment: Before you do, check all the other servers in the farm and ensure that they are not attempting to start as well.